Can't find a package for duotone thin
Hello using the https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome package in an angular project. I have installed and have working (using pro). When searching on fontawesome website there is an option for duotone-thin. The only package I see when installing for angular on duotone is @fortawesome/pro-duotone-svg-icons. This is the regular duotone icons. I can't find a package for duotone thin. Is it not possible to use the duotone thin icons with the angular fontawesome package? Thanks.

@fortawesome/duotone-thin-svg-icons is the package name I believe. Will be added to ng add in the next release.

@YaroslavAdmin. That worked thanks! if you want to answer Ill mark as answered

You'll need to install @fortawesome/duotone-thin-svg-icons package using:
$ npm install @fortawesome/duotone-thin-svg-icons

All available Pro icon package names can be found on the FontAwesome website: https://docs.fontawesome.com/web/setup/packages#svg-icon-packages
